# How do I fix a fallen-off facade?

Tags: repair, walls, crack

We live in a block of apartments made from bricks, and the wall outside one window is damaged. We have a clothes hanger attached to that wall, and one screw has already fallen off, and wall around the second one on that side is cracked.

[image: Damaged Wall]

Is there an easy way to fix it, considering the fact, I have no experience with such things? What materials or tools do I need for this?

Comment: I can't tell from the picture -- is the building made of concrete block? That doesn't look like brick.

Comment: well now I'm not sure.. I was pretty sure it was bricks, but now I don't know, we live here short time and there are neighbours who say brick, and ones who say concrete.

Comment: Looks like stucco over brick maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The only appropriate answer is that you need to get your landlord involved.  The fix involves stucco, primer, paint, etc.